# Grid View Cells programmatically coloured loses color on postback

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, webforms, postback

I am working on grid view which has coloured cells based on their content. I have coloured them on RowDataBound event. But whenever their is a post back in the page the colours are lost.

Comment: Show how you have colored them in `RowDataBound`. The color is not persisted in viewstate, so you need to re-color it on every postback. One way: use `RowCreated` instead. The problem, there you don't have the datasource.

Comment: As @TimSchmelter said, what you do in code behind is not automatically persisted for you. If you did the coloring in the `RowDataBound` event then this event is not firing again, and your colors are reset to default values, which is by design in webforms. You could wrap your grid in an update panel and make sure that it does not update when it doesn't need to, which would make the colors stick. Whenever the grid needs a refresh then, it will rebind to the data and your colors will be applied again. You will need to use the panel's `UpdateMode` property for that, which is `always` by default.

Comment: Thanks.. Solved it by storing the datatable i used as datasource in a view state and using it during rowcreated

Answer (score 1):

As rightly pointed out by @TimSchmelter and @julealgon coloring done in rowdatabound doesnot persists on postback. So I did the coloring in RowCreated. However datasource was not available there so I stored the datatable that I had used as a datasource during binding the grid in a viewstate and accessed the datatable rows using the row index e.row.rowIndex in rowcreated and performed coloring using the data at row created event

Comment: I know this has worked for you, but I'd very strongly suggest against storing the data in viewstate. You see, everything you store in the viewstate is passed to the client and goes back to the server at every roundtrip. This might seem insignificant at times, but if your data is actually large, you may have very serious problems there. We ended up with a page being 11mb of html once and had to redesign it.

Comment: @julealgon Is there some other way to access data in row created?

Comment: Perhaps you could update your OP with more information, like how exactly you are updating the color, what is the code in the `rowdatabound` event, how the markup is setup etc. You really have no way to access the data in the `rowcreated` event without saving it somewhere (viewstate/session/etc), but I wanted to see exactly what you are trying to do and how, to maybe suggest an alternative that wouldn't rely on that.